# query sqllite database by the first letter of an entry

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I have created a TabLayout and I want to display the entries of my database by the selected tab. Here is the code snippet with the query:

```
public Cursor filteredItems(int tabPosition) throws SQLException {
        Log.d(TAG, "filteredItems called, Parameter: "+tabPosition); 

        String filter = ""; 
        if(tabPosition == 0){
            filter = "[a-cA-C]%";
        }else if(tabPosition == 1){
            filter = "[d-fD-F]%";
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "default tab"); 
            filter = "[a-zA-Z]%";
        }

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try{
            open();
            String query ="SELECT _id, surname, prename, street, zipcode, telephone, email FROM "+Database.getMyDbTable()+" " +
                    "WHERE surname LIKE '"+filter+"';";
            Log.d(TAG,"Query "+query);
            cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get list");
            CharSequence text = dataNotFound;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

        return cursor;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the filter does not work - the result of the query is always empty(the table is not empty - I have checked it).

Comment: What about **Like 'filter%'** ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use wildcards for this purpose. Read at http://sqlite.awardspace.info/syntax/sqlitepg03.htm

Try

```
SELECT _id, surname, prename, street, zipcode, telephone, email FROM table WHERE surname LIKE '<your letter(s)>%'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the LIKE operator does not take regular expressions. The REGEXP operator that does this is, unfortunately, not supported in Android.

Solution: use LIKE with logical OR.

```
String query ="SELECT _id, surname, prename, street, zipcode, telephone, email FROM "+Database.getMyDbTable()+" WHERE surname LIKE 'a%' OR surname LIKE 'b%' OR surname LIKE 'c%';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
"SELECT _id, surname, prename, street, zipcode, telephone, email FROM " + Database.getMyDbTable() + " WHERE substr(" + Database.getMyDbTable()  +",1) LIKE " + <yourletter>
```

By using `substr`, you're comparing only the first letter.

Comment: @CL. You can just take a bigger substr and add more letters to the match

Comment: But how would you match all values beginning with letters A-C?

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` cannot match with character sets.

Since you care only for the first letter, you can use `BETWEEN` instead:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE surname BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Czzzz'
```

To handle both upper and lower case, either use two conditions, or change the collation:

```
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE surname BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Czzzz'
                           OR surname BETWEEN 'a' AND 'czzzz'

SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE surname COLLATION UNICODE BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Czzzz'
```

The latter can use an index only if the column or index has been declared with the same collation.